# Scaffolding to find missing values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scaffolding

I have a time series data set. For each date, I should have the following:

| Category | Sub-category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 |
| A | A2 | 2 |
| B | B1 | 3 |
| B | B2 | 4 |

However, I do have sometimes missing values, something like:

| Category | Sub-category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 |
| B | B2 | 4 |

What I want to do is identify missing values for each date. So with the above, it would be:

| Category | Sub-category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 |
| A | A2 | NULL |
| B | B1 | NULL |
| B | B2 | 4 |

To do that, I have created a table like this in Snowflake called `scaffold`:

| Category | Sub-category |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1 |
| A | A2 |
| B | B1 |
| B | B2 |

And I have written the following query:

```
select 
a.date
,b.category
,b.subcategory
,a.value

  
from main_table a
right outer join scaffold b
on a.category=b.category
and a.subcategory=b.subcategory
```

Strangely, my output stays the same as illustrated below - it's as if I wasn't using this scaffold:

| Category | Sub-category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 1 |
| B | B2 | 4 |

I've tried changing the join to a full outer join, to no avail. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend cross joining the expected categories / subcategories (`scaffold`) with the list of distinct dates that are available in the main table.

This gives you all possible combinations (ie all rows of the resultset); then, the main table can be brought with a `left join` - when the join does not match, the `value` end up as `null`:

```
select d.date, s.category, s.subcategory, m.value
from (select distinct date from main_table) d
cross join scaffold s
left join main_table m 
    on  m.date        = d.date 
    and m.category    = s.category
    and m.subcategory = s.subcategory
```

Ideally you would have a separate table that stores the dates only, which we would use instead of `select distinct` in subquery `d`.

Comment: Hi @GMB thank you very much for this answer! in your select clause, you write s.value. You do mean m.value instead, right? That answer works! I'm really keen to understand what I was doing wrong if you have the chance to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

First inner join the table with your small scaffold, to get a full scaffold. Then right the original table join to the full scaffold.